How to determine destination for UDP packets, at proxy server?
I need to route TCP and UDP packets via a proxy server, at layer 4 (i.e. without TLS termination, for TCP packets). The destination address for all packets is not fixed. In other words, the routing needs to be dynamic and the destination for each packet can be determined based on destination hostname/IP in the packet. So, TCP/TLS packets can easily be routed based on SNI because all TCP in my case is TLS. However, UDP packets cannot be, as SNI is typically for TCP and its equivalent does not seem to be present in UDP.
I was looking at envoy proxy's DestinationIPInput filter to cater to this problem but it is based on HAProxy Proxy protocol, which doesn't seem to support UDP.
Is there a standard proxy protocol, using which a proxy server can determine the destination server address (and port) for UDP packets coming to it from a client (which can also send the packets in compliance with the same protocol) ? Will be good, if the same protocol can support TCP/HTTP proxying too.


the destination for each packet can be determined based on destination hostname/IP in the packet. So, TCP packets can easily be routed based on SNI.

There is no SNI in TCP packets.
There is SNI in TLS, but not all TCP is TLS.
And, it is only in the application payload of the packets after the TCP handshake is already finished, i.e. one gets this information only with the first data packets after TCP handshake.

Is there a standard proxy protocol, using which a proxy server can determine the destination server address (and port)

If the clients directly contacts the proxy (for example because DNS lookup returns its IP for the hostname the client wants to access), then the only information available is that the client wanted to access the proxy - no information about some inner "real" destination.
To extract the "real" inner destination the client would need to actually use it in the first place and the traffic to this inner destination would need to be routed through the proxy which would need to be transparent. Only then the proxy could extract the original destination IP/port at layer 3/4. Details on how to write such a transparent proxy and integrate it into the routing depend on the OS - see for example Transparent proxy support in Linux.
If you control the client side and need a standard protocol which encapsulates the necessary information about the "real" inner destination by the client directly, then you can use SOCKS5.

Yes, I did mean SNI in TLS (probably should have mentioned it too; thanks for correcting). This is not a problem for TCP packets in my case because all TCP here is TLS and proxies like haproxy (for e.g.) can be configured in 'tcp' mode to route traffic based on SNI in TLS' ClientHello.
